# What time is NASA using for Horizons web output?

Tags: time, jpl-horizons

Here's an example of some output from JPL's [Horizons web interface](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi).

NASA does not (appear to) specify *which GMT* is at those hours that the specific transits occurred, or at least I can't find it.

Should I assume its UTC 0 or GMT 0? Thanks!

```
2019-Dec-19 06:52:31.872     223.20921 -16.31128 223.20931 -16.31131 340.624206  37.520282
2019-Dec-19 12:26:29.760     223.86907 -16.58967 223.86916 -16.58970 341.077681  36.930691
2019-Dec-19 18:00:27.648     224.52893 -16.86521 224.52902 -16.86524 341.522894  36.341088
```

Answer (score 2):

See the FAQ of the JPL's website:

> Coordinate time is the time used in the development of ephemerides
>   for solar system objects. Under General Relativity, the rate at which
>   actual clocks tick is called proper time. The rate of proper time
>   depends on the location and motion of the clock, so there is no single
>   proper time for the solar system as a whole. So for representing the
>   motions of he solar system bodies using numerical integration, a time
>   scale called 'coordinate time' is used, which is not the rate of any
>   physical clock, but a parameter for which the equations of motion are
>   simply expressed.
>
> The integrated ephemerides for solar system bodies are stored as
>   tables of positions and velocities as a function of coordinate time.
>   In order to evaluate a measurement, such as the round-trip light time
>   from Earth to Mars, or the direction to Saturn as seen from Earth, the
>   proper times of the measurement must be converted to coordinate time
>   before looking up the positions.
>
> Currently the International Astronomical Union (IAU) has defined two
>   coordinate times for the solar system and both are equally accurate.
>   The coordinate time used for the JPL ephemerides, as the independent
>   variable in the solar system, barycentric relativistic, equations of
>   motion, is Barycentric Dynamical Time (TDB) or, in French, Temps
>   Dynamique Barycentrique. This coordinate time is defined such that in
>   the vicinity of the Earth the difference in coordinate time and
>   international atomic time (TAI) is 32.184 seconds plus a small
>   variation that is less than 3 milliseconds. TAI differs from Universal
>   Coordinate Time (UTC) by an integer number of seconds (34 as of July
>   1, 2012), which changes only when leap seconds are added. UTC is the
>   basis for civil time (e.g., Pacific Standard Time equals UTC - 8
>   hours).

**So the time is neither UTC nor GMT, it is TDB to avoid the problems with leap seconds.**

Many thanks to Christiano for finding my error about TAI.

Comment: Are you sure? I read: "The coordinate time used for the JPL ephemerides, [...], is Barycentric Dynamical Time (TDB)" not TAI. AFAIK, TAI is never used and all the JPL ephemerides use TDB. That's true also for EPM and INPOP ephemerides.